# how do I create grid view which shows column as per selected?

Tags: asp.net

How do I create `Grid View` as per selected columns?

I have List of `check boxes` with column name. As user select check box and save it, the gird view show me with selected columns.

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. If You want to hide some columns then try this:

```
        for (int i = gridView.Columns.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (gridView.Columns[i].GetType().Name == "columnName"
                || gridView.Columns[i].GetType().Name == "columnOtherName")
            {
                gridView.Columns[i].Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

EDIT:

So You have list of checkboxes with auto postback enabled:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="checkBoxList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="column 1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="column 2" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="column 3" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="column 4" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="column 5" />
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

and then You have Your gridview with row create event:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated"/>
```

In code behind for row create event You can change visibility of cells based on checkbox state:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxList1.Items.Count; i++)
        e.Row.Cells[i].Visible = checkBoxList1.Items[i].Selected; 
}
```

and thats it. You can hide columns that way, even for autogenerated gridview. I assume here that Your gridview has 5 columns bound to it.

Comment: i.e I have 5 columns in grid, and 5 Check Box with column name[which are outside from grid],If user unchecked the Check Box then that item column should be hide from grid view.

Comment: Try the solution that I added to my answer

Answer (score 0):

On save button click (assuming order of items in checkboxlist is same as column in grid):

```
      int index = 0;
      foreach (var checkbox in checkBoxList.Items)
      {
          if(checkbox.Selected)
           {
           GridView1.Columns[index].Visible = true;
          }
        else
         {
          GridView1.Columns[index].Visible = false;
          }
        index++;
      }
```